# Polymer iron-form - disable submit?

Tags: post, polymer

I'm using `iron-form` and I'm trying to `POST` a file to a (currently local) server. I'm having two buttons, one to actually send the file and one to cancel. I'm having a problem cancelling. Here's the form:

```
<form  is="iron-form" action="http://localhost:7733/receivedoc" id="restForm" method="post" >
  <table class="starter-inputs">
    <tr><td>
    <px-file-upload 
      id="uploadComponentId"
      message="Drag and drop files here, or click the button below." 
      multiple=false 
      accept=".xls,.xlsx">
    </px-file-upload>
    </td></tr>
    </table>
    <button class="btn btn--large btn--icon" id="saveDataSetButton">
      <i class="fa-briefcase">Generate Pacing File</i>
    </button>
    <button class="btn btn--large btn--icon" id="cancelDataSetButton">
      <i class="fa-briefcase">Cancel</i>
    </button>
    <div class="output"></div>
  </form>
```

The `cancelDataSetButton` is being handled as:

```
this.$.cancelDataSetButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
  console.log('restForm.cancelDataSetButton click')
  restForm.reset();
  restForm.querySelector('.output').innerHTML = 'Operation cancelled.';
});
```

HOWEVER, since [By default, a native  element (or input type="submit") will submit this form.](https://github.com/PolymerElements/iron-form), the `POST` gets fired regardless. How can I prevent the Cancel button from `POST`ing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's a good question.

Couple things I would like to highlight here...

First of all, let's refresh some basics regarding HTML spec:

1) `<button>` without attribute `type` will act as `type=submit` as default attribute, that's why **both of your buttons will submit** the form.

2) `<button>` is supporting `type="reset"` which will reset all your fields into initial value(s) (e.g. clear them) and **will not submit a form**, so there are no JS handler code is needed for that at all.

In total, I would recommend to do some adjustments in your HTML code, related to buttons block:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn--large btn--icon" id="saveDataSetButton">
    <i class="fa-briefcase">Generate Pacing File</i>
</button>
<button type="reset" class="btn btn--large btn--icon" id="cancelDataSetButton">
    <i class="fa-briefcase">Cancel</i>
</button>
```

Please make note, that for `cancelDataSetButton` no JS code is needed (to clear the field), and you could delete whole event listener:

`this.$.cancelDataSetButton.addEventListener('click', function() {`
and so one.

Some references to catch up:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button